# Large-size taxi options in Tokyo

Tags: japan, taxis, tokyo

What are the largest sized taxi options in Tokyo and how to order them? We'll need to travel with 4 people, each with a mid-to-large sized suitcase. The last time we did, we got one of the newer style S.RIDE taxis, but the suitcases had to be tied up in the trunk as it wouldn’t close, and we still had to take one into the passenger cabin. It wasn’t a very comfortable ride.

So for the next time, is there any bigger option? Uber offers a “Black van” option, but it’s not quite clear to me how roomy that is exactly. I’d prefer to not have to try to get two taxis.

Comment: Note: this’ll be mostly to get to the airport, and I’m aware of the option of sending the suitcases there in advance. But I’d prefer to just get a bigger taxi, if possible.

Comment: If I was you, I would just not bother with that, just send your suitcases there and take the train, especially seeing the taxi price for Narita (and even Haneda in a way smaller measure)

Comment: I won't be going all the way to the airport by taxi; just Shinjuku, and hop on the N'EX from there. It's the getting to Shinjuku part that would be a huge hassle without taxi.

Comment: Is taking two taxis an option?

Comment: Have you contacted the taxi company you're working with to explain the situation to them to ask for a recommendation? We had to change reservations when we (family of 4) left London after the hotel clerk overheard our conversation, he told us the car we got wouldn't fit us all. We called back, explained our needs and they sent a different one. (No, this wasn't a London Taxi, it was an Uber-like service.)

Comment: @FreeMan I’m not exactly “working with” any taxi company. I’m just hailing them. ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Uber offers "Black Van" in Japan, it should be enough to accommodate your needs.

A quick google search showed "Toyota Alphard" as the common option for this ride, it's a big car!

[image]

Comment: An Alphard would indeed work very well. Thank you.

Comment: Can confirm that when we ordered a Uber Black Van in Japan, it was always an Alphrad that showed up. Plenty of room for 4 and 4 large suitcases

Answer (score 2):

Doing some more research, a number of taxi companies in Tokyo do offer large size taxis, usually Toyota Alphards or comparable cars, and/or even mini buses. Some only offer this as quite pricy premium services, whereas others offer it as regular taxis with a certain surcharge (around +¥2,000).

The GO taxi app may offer a "GO Premium" option, *if you enter both your pickup and destination*. Skipping the destination, the premium option won't appear, since it's limited to certain areas.

[image: GO app showing premium option]

It's unlikely you'll find these taxis randomly driving around, as they don't typically sport the usual taxi signage. GO Premium taxis only have a small "GO Premium" sticker near the door, but no indicator whether they're available or occupied; so random hailing on the street will be tricky. If anything, you may get lucky at some larger taxi stands.

Googling for "<area name> wagon taxi" or 「〇〇大型タクシー」, 「〇〇ワゴンタクシー」 should bring up results in your area, which you can either reserve online or call directly.

Of course, as Nean answered, Uber is also a convenient way to book these.